# Why did my escalation rule trigger early?

Tags: case

I have an escalation rule setup as follows:

- Rule Name: Idle Notification
- Active: Checked

I only have 1 rule entry and it has the following attributes:

- Rule Criteria:  (Case: Status not equal to Closed) and (Case: Case Owner equals ExampleQueue)
- Business Hours Settings: Set business hours on case with "Default"
- How escalation times are set: Based on when the case is created.

I have 1 escalation action:

- Age over: 0 Hours 30 Minutes
- Additional emails: foo@foo.com

I then created a case at 12:25 PM and assigned it to ExampleQueue.  The escalation triggered at 12:45 PM (only 20 minutes later).

So I'm really confused.  I understand that SalesForce only checks escalations every 15 minutes so I would have expected to receive a notification at 1:00 PM (at which time the case would technically be 35 minutes old).

Why did it trigger early?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two effects that come into play.

First, escalation rules are evaluated every 15 minutes, but it's not every 15 minutes within the hour-- it's every 15 minutes once the escalation processing service starts. For example, if the server starts up at 5 minutes after the hour, the service will escalate at 12:05, 12:20, 12: 35, 12:50, and 1:05 (etc). That means after each maintenance where a server restart occurs, the service will be staggered by the server's start time offset.

Secondly, there's a feature called "Early escalation rules", which basically subtracts 15 minutes off of the escalation time so it will run one escalation cycle earlier. It's apparent that you have early escalation triggers turned on, because if you didn't, it would have escalated at 1:00 PM instead of 12:45 PM. See [Knowledge Article Number: 000005623](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005623&language=en_US) for more information on early escalation rules.

You can configure early triggers in Setup > Customize > Cases > Support Settings.